# SQL0199N error when trying to connect HammerDB to Db2 for z/OS

Tags: db2, db2-zos, hammerdb

I'm trying to generate some data for DB2 11.1 z/OS using HammerDB v3.1 which is running on a Windows remote host. There is no ability to run HammerDB on the same host with DB2.
According to the [HammerDB documentation](http://www.example.com/) I need to set up IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI.

What I did:

1. Downloaded and set up the driver for 11.1 on HammerDB host - v11.1.4fp4_ntx64_odbc_cli.zip as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/t0023866.html?view=kc)
2. Configure db2dsdriver.cfg file

```
<configuration>
   <dsncollection>
      <dsn alias="TPCC" name="<my database name>" host="<my host name>" port="50000"/>
      <!-- Long aliases are supported -->
      <dsn alias="longaliasname2" name="name2" host="server2.net1.com" port="55551">
         <parameter name="Authentication" value="SERVER_ENCRYPT"/>
      </dsn>
   </dsncollection>
   <databases>
      <database name="<my database name>" host="<my host name>" port="50000">
         <parameter name="CurrentSchema" value="OWNER1"/>
         .......
```

3. Add environment variable DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH

`set DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH=C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\C_IBMDB2_CLIDRIVER_clidriver\cfg`

4. Run HammerDB GUI, try to build a schema and receive

````
Error in Virtual User 1: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0199N  The use of the reserved word "INDEX" following "" is not valid.  Expected tokens may include:  "ORGANIZE APPEND VOLATILE AUDIT VALIDPROC EDITPROC OBID IN DATA".  SQLSTATE=42601```
````

Comment: You might find the Hammerdb discussion forum on sourceforge useful. A CLI trace will help. If you know how to read TCL, you can see the source also in the hammerdb installation directory tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to understand the root cause of the problem is to trace the CLI driver.
[Tracing the CLI driver by using the db2trc on -cli command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/t0060829.html)
Something like this on the DB2 Data Server Client side:

> db2trc on -cli -f *trc.dmp*
>   `steps to reproduce the problem`
>   db2trc off
>   db2trc fmt -cli *trc.dmp* *trc.dmp.txt*

The *trc.dmp.txt* file will have exact statements the client tried to run.